# Is there a saying in English that expresses "Life is a mercy to get born"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request, idiom-request

> Life is a mercy to get born

It's coming from this thinking that this life is an opportunity, but this opportunity is given to us based on absolute love (mercy).

"To get born" in this sentence is coming from this thinking that we are unaware conscious/souls that we actually will be born when we become aware of our true selves (that's how a conscious should get born when it become aware).

I'm not sure how to translate to convey the meaning. Any suggestion is appreciated.

In Persian the original sentence is:

> زندگی رحمتی است برای متولد شدن

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, and I don't really understand what you are trying to say.  For example "absolute love" is not the same thing as "mercy", and there is nothing about opportunities in the phrase.  Perhaps you could see what the automatic translators make of your sentence.  If you go to google translate and put your phrase in you native language.  Sometimes it mangles the English, but sometimes it gives helpful translations, at least it gives a second opinion.

Comment: "Life is a mercy to be born" is from google translate. 

what I explained is what we can sense in the original language. but not sure how to pass it through the translation

Comment: _Be born_  is much better than _get born_. There seems to be so much meaning packed into this short sentence that it is difficult for someone from another culture to know exactly how to translate it.

Comment: I think that this is equivalent to the maxim "life is a gift". Google it and see what you think.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of context from the Koran and from the Persian culture about the nature of "mercy".  In English, mercy is about showing kindness to someone that you have the power to harm.  The Farsi رحمت is (from my limited understanding) much deeper.  Mercy is an abstract and normally uncountable noun. We can speak of an act of mercy, but it might be better to say "and act of love" in this context. (Christian English culture speaks of "God is Love" rather than "God is mercy")

It doesn't make sense to say "Life is a mercy", nor "life is love", but there is a reasonably well know saying "Life is a gift".  So I'd suggest:

> Life is a gift and so birth is an act of Love.

I'm capitalising Love, to mean Love as an attribute or nature of God, rather than ordinary love between humans.

But as Kate says, there is so much culture packed into that expression, that no translation is going to be complete.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I like your translation, but it doesn't pass this gift is given. this gift is given so these unborn consciousnesses (us, humans) have an opportunity to be born (by becoming conscious of themselves). is this one look better to you? "Life is a gift of Love to us to be born", or better if we can remove "us" from the sentence

Comment: Life is the gift of Love through birth  (Ie Being born is the way that we receive the gift of life from Love (here a personification of a loving God, I suppose)